# can't add create react app content to repo

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I am trying to create react app and i have a nodejs (express) backend

here is a link to the  [repo](https://github.com/moaoa/cards-game)
as you can see in the repo the file client is empty

and I can't add (stage) the client file
when I do `git add.` then  `git status` 
I get the following message

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in
submodules)
    modified:   client (modified content, untracked content)
    modified:   package.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I tried `git add .` , `git add client` 
but nothing works i can't push the client file to github

`ls -all` returns this :

```
total 55
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121     0 Jun 20 16:38 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121     0 Jun 20 15:11 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121     0 Jun 21 10:24 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121    15 Jun 20 15:18 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121     0 Jun 20 15:57 client/
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121     0 Jun 20 15:14 node_modules/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121   362 Jun 20 17:14 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 14290 Jun 20 15:14 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121   389 Jun 20 15:17 server.js
```

Comment: have you tried to `git commit -m "message"` after `git add .` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+modified+content%2C+untracked+content

Comment: Yes I did that but when I go to github I see the client file empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try execute

`git rm -rf --cached client`

and

`git add client`

in the client directory.

Comment: Can you execute "ls -al" command and update question?

Comment: is there any file in client directory?

Comment: I cloned repo and did:
`git rm -r --cached client`
`git add .`
and git took files from client directory. So maybe copy files from project (that which cannot be added), delete repository, do clone once again and make this commands which I made.

Comment: yes my problem was solved i ran these commands in this specific order: 
    `git rm -rf --cached client  ` then 
then    `cd client`
    `rm .git `
    `git add .`
and the problem was solved thank you :)